# Finding the MLE for $θ$ given a probability density function $f(y |\theta )$.

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

> Let $Y_1$, $Y_2$, . . . , $Y_n$ denote a random sample from the probability density function
>   $$f (y | θ)=\begin{cases} (θ + 1)y^θ, &  0 < y < 1; θ > −1,\\ 0 ,& \text{elsewhere.}\end{cases}$$ 
>   Find the MLE  for $θ$.

My approach is first
$$L(\theta) = (\theta+1)^n \biggl(\prod_{i=1}^n y_i\biggr)^{\!\theta}$$
$$\ln L(\theta) = n \ln (\theta+1) + \theta \sum_{i=1}^n  \ln y_i$$

Taking the derivative of it, we got $$\frac{d \ln L(\theta)}{d \theta} = n\frac{1}{\theta+1} + \sum_{i=1}^n \ln y_i$$

Setting it to zero, we got $$\frac{n}{\theta+1} = - \sum_{i=1}^n \ln y_i $$

Then $$\hat{\theta} = \frac{-n}{\sum_{i=1}^n \ln y_i} - 1$$

However, the answer is $$\hat{\theta} = \frac{-n}{\sum_{i=1}^n \ln y_i}$$

I am wondering what part of my answer is wrong. Could someone please help figure it out?

Comment: There are several mistakes here. 

First, the exponent of $(1+\theta)$ in your likelihood function should be $n$, not $2$. 

Next, after taking the logarithm you got an extra $n$ outside, $(1+\theta)$ somehow escaped the $\ln$, and you also have an extra $y_i$ outside the $\ln$.

The log likelihood should be 
$$
  \ln L(\theta;y_1,\ldots,y_n)
= n\ln(\theta+1) + \theta \sum_{i=1}^n \ln(y_i).
$$
You did end up with the correct derivative though, so I assume these were just typos.

Comment: @user139388 I have corrected the typos, thanks.

Comment: For what it's worth. I see no mistake in your approach. Are you sure this is the complete question?

Comment: To confirm, you think $$\hat{\theta} = \frac{-n}{\sum_{i=1}^n \ln y_i} - 1$$ is the right answer?

Comment: Yeah, regardless how many $y_i$ you have as long as $0<y_i<1$, then using your calculation the value of $\theta$ will always greater than $-1$. So, I think it's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is correct; the provided answer is the MLE of $\theta + 1$, not $\theta$.  You can see this either through simulation, or by direct calculation:  if we let $$s = -\sum_{i=1}^n \log y_i > 0,$$ then $$\hat \theta = -1 + \frac{n}{s},$$ and $$\ell(\hat\theta \mid s) = n \log(\hat \theta + 1) - \hat\theta s = s + n \log \tfrac{n}{s} - n.$$  But $$\ell(\hat \theta + 1 \mid s) = n \log \left(\tfrac{n}{s} + 1\right) - n$$  So their difference is $$d(s,n) = \ell(\hat\theta \mid s) - \ell(\hat\theta + 1 \mid s) = s + n \log \frac{n}{n+s}.$$  It is easy to show that this expression is always positive for $s > 0$ and $n = 1, 2, 3, \ldots$:  its derivative with respect to $s$ is $\frac{s}{n+s} > 0$, so it is strictly increasing, and $d(0,n) = 0$.  This proves that the estimator $n/s$ yields a strictly smaller log-likelihood than your correct MLE $\hat \theta = -1 + n/s$.

Comment: wait a minute... so $$\hat{\theta} = \frac{-n}{\sum_{i=1}^n \ln y_i} - 1$$ is right?

Comment: Yes.  That is the correct answer.

Comment: If you have time, could you look at a related post http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/750773/compare-two-estimators-by-using-the-their-expected-value-and-variances

Comment: You don't rate my answers, so my response is no.

Comment: just forgot it! here you go