# Let $Y_1, Y_2,\ldots,Y_n$ denote a random sample from the uniform distrib... Help find finding $ \text{Var}\left[\hat{\theta}_{2}\right]$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $Y_1, Y_2,\ldots,Y_n$ denote a random sample from the uniform distribution on the interval $(θ, θ + 1)$. Let $$ \hat{\theta}_2 = Y_{(n)} - \frac{n}{n+1}$$

Find the efficiency of $θ^1$ relative to $θ^2$

We have $Y_i\sim\mathcal{U}(\theta,\theta+1)$ and CDF of $Y_i$ based on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_%28continuous%29)
$$
G_{Y_i}(y)=\Pr[Y_i\le y]=\frac{y-\theta}{\theta+1-\theta}=y-\theta.
$$
Here, $Y_{(n)}$ is $n$-th order statistics. Therefore, $Y_{(n)}=\max[Y_1,\ldots, Y_n]$. Note that $Y_{(n)}\le y$ equivalence to $Y_i\le y$ for $i=1,2,\ldots,n$. Hence, for $\theta< y<\theta+1$, the fact that $Y_1,Y_2,\ldots, Y_n$ are **i.i.d.** implies
$$
G_{Y_{(n)}}(y)=\Pr[Y_{(n)}\le y]=\Pr[Y_1\le y,Y_2\le y,\ldots, Y_n\le y]=(\Pr[Y_i\le y])^n=\left(y-\theta\right)^{n}.
$$
The PDF of $Y_{(n)}$ is
$$
g_{Y_{(n)}}(y)=\frac{d}{dy}G_{Y_{(n)}}(y)=\frac{d}{dy}(y-\theta)^n=n(y-\theta)^{n-1}.
$$
The expected value of $Y_{(n)}$ is
$$
\begin{align}
\text{E}\left[Y_{(n)}\right]&=\int_{y=\theta}^{\theta+1}yg_{Y_{(n)}}(y)\ dy\\
&=\int_{y=\theta}^{\theta+1}yn(y-\theta)^{n-1}\ dy\\
&=n\int_{y=\theta}^{\theta+1}y(y-\theta)^{n-1}\ dy.
\end{align}
$$

I have trouble finding  $$
\text{Var}\left[\hat{\theta}_{2}\right]=\text{Var}\left[Y_{(n)}-\frac{n}{n+1}\right]=\text{Var}\left[Y_{(n)}\right]=\text{E}\left[Y_{(n)}^2\right]-\left(\text{E}\left[Y_{(n)}\right]\right)^2.
$$

I found that
$$
\begin{align}
\text{E}\left[Y_{(n)}\right]&=n\left[\frac{y(y-\theta)^n}{n+1}-\frac{\theta(y-\theta)^n}{n(n+1)}\right]_{y=\theta}^{\theta+1}\\
&=\frac{n(\theta+1)}{n+1}+\frac{\theta}{n+1}\\
&=\theta+\frac{n}{n+1}.
\end{align}
$$

The way I calculate $E(Y_{(n)}^2)$ is the following:

$$E(Y_{(n)}^2) = ny^2(y-\theta)^{n-1} = n\left[\left.y^2\frac{(y-\theta)^n}{n} \right|_\theta^{\theta+1} - \frac{2}{n} \int_\theta^{\theta+1} y(y-\theta)^n  \,dy\right]$$

$$= \left.(\theta+1)^2 - 2\left(y\frac{(y-\theta)^{n+1}}{n+1} \right|_\theta^{\theta+1} - \int_\theta^{\theta+1} \frac{(y-\theta)^{n+1}}{n+1} dy\right) = (\theta+1)^2 -2 \left(\frac{\theta+1}{n+1} - \left.\frac{(y-\theta)^{n+2}}{(n+1)(n+2)}\right|_\theta^{\theta+1}\right)$$

$$= (\theta+1)^2- 2\frac{\theta +1}{n+1} - \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}$$

Then I use $E(Y_{(n)}^2) - E(Y_{(n)})^2$, based on wolframalpha which gives me the following result ...please go [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x%2b1%29%5E2-2%28%28x%2b1%29/%28n%2b1%29%29%20%2b%201/%28%28n%2b1%29%28n%2b2%29%29%20-%20%28%28x%2b1%29%20-%201/%28n%2b1%29%29%5E2)  ...which is different from the correct answer $\text {Var} [\hat{\theta}_2]= V(Y(n))=\frac{n}{(n+2)(n+1)^2}$....Could anyone please check why?

Comment: I already tried what I knew .... I just wanted to see if someone can help spot my mistake...

Comment: Try to fix the formula. What is $Y_{(n)}$?

Comment: If it is appropriate for you to be seeking such help, then please ask your tutor: then they will understand what part you have been able to answer yourself, and be able to mark accordingly.

Comment: @leonbloy: I tried my best to fix the formula...but it still looks the way it does...but you could focus on the answer...I just edited my questions to see if that address your concern on $Y_{(n)}$

Comment: @leonbloy: just fix the formule

Comment: As far I know, displaystyle `$$ ...$$` is not allowed in title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variance can be evaluated as follows
$$
\text{Var}\left[\hat{\theta}_{2}\right]=\text{Var}\left[Y_{(n)}-\frac{n}{n+1}\right]=\text{Var}\left[Y_{(n)}\right]=\text{E}\left[Y_{(n)}^2\right]-\left(\text{E}\left[Y_{(n)}\right]\right)^2.
$$
First, we calculate $\text{E}\left[Y_{(n)}^2\right]$. Using the result from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/749508/123277), we obtain
$$
\text{E}\left[Y_{(n)}^2\right]=n\int_{y=\theta}^{\theta+1}y^2(y-\theta)^{n-1}\ dy.
$$
Using IBP, let $u=y^2\Rightarrow du=2y\ dy$ and $dv=(y-\theta)^{n-1}\ dy\Rightarrow v=\dfrac{(y-\theta)^n}{n}$. Hence
$$
\begin{align}
n\int_{y=\theta}^{\theta+1}y^2(y-\theta)^{n-1}\ dy&=n\left[\left.\dfrac{y^2(y-\theta)^n}{n}\right|_{y=\theta}^{\theta+1}-\int_{y=\theta}^{\theta+1}\dfrac{(y-\theta)^n}{n} 2y\ dy\right]\\
&=(\theta+1)^2-2\int_{y=\theta}^{\theta+1}y(y-\theta)^{n}\ dy\;\;\;\Rightarrow\;\;\;\text{again we use IBP here.}\\
&=(\theta+1)^2-2\left[\left.\dfrac{y(y-\theta)^{n+1}}{n+1}\right|_{y=\theta}^{\theta+1}-\int_{y=\theta}^{\theta+1}\dfrac{(y-\theta)^{n+2}}{n+1} dy\right]\\
&=(\theta+1)^2-2\left[\dfrac{\theta+1}{n+1}-\left.\dfrac{(y-\theta)^{n+2}}{(n+1)(n+2)}\right|_{y=\theta}^{\theta+1}\right]\\
\text{E}\left[Y_{(n)}^2\right]&=(\theta+1)^2-\dfrac{2(\theta+1)}{n+1}+\dfrac{2}{(n+1)(n+2)}.
\end{align}
$$
You already have
$$
\text{E}\left[Y_{(n)}\right]=\theta+\frac{n}{n+1}.
$$
Thus
$$
\begin{align}
\text{Var}\left[\hat{\theta}_{2}\right]&=\text{E}\left[Y_{(n)}^2\right]-\left(\text{E}\left[Y_{(n)}\right]\right)^2\\
&=(\theta+1)^2-\dfrac{2(\theta+1)}{n+1}+\dfrac{2}{(n+1)(n+2)}-\left(\theta+\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^2\\
&=\theta^2+2\theta+1-\dfrac{2(\theta+1)}{n+1}+\dfrac{2}{(n+1)(n+2)}-\theta^2-\frac{2n\theta}{n+1}-\frac{n^2}{(n+1)^2}\\
&=\dfrac{(2\theta+1)(n+1)-2(\theta+1)}{n+1}+\dfrac{2}{(n+1)(n+2)}-\frac{2n\theta}{n+1}-\frac{n^2}{(n+1)^2}\\
&=\dfrac{2n\theta+2\theta+n+1-2\theta-2}{n+1}+\dfrac{2}{(n+1)(n+2)}-\frac{2n\theta}{n+1}-\frac{n^2}{(n+1)^2}\\
&=\dfrac{2n\theta+n-1}{n+1}+\dfrac{2}{(n+1)(n+2)}-\frac{2n\theta}{n+1}-\frac{n^2}{(n+1)^2}\\
&=\dfrac{n-1}{n+1}+\dfrac{2}{(n+1)(n+2)}-\frac{n^2}{(n+1)^2}\\
&=\dfrac{(n-1)(n+1)+2}{(n+1)(n+2)}-\frac{n^2}{(n+1)^2}\\
&=\dfrac{n(n+1)}{(n+1)(n+2)}-\frac{n^2}{(n+1)^2}\\
&=\dfrac{n}{n+2}-\frac{n^2}{(n+1)^2}\\
&=\frac{n(n+1)^2-n^2(n+2)}{(n+2)(n+1)^2}\\
&=\frac{n}{(n+2)(n+1)^2}.
\end{align}
$$

$$\\$$

---

$$\Large\color{blue}{\text{# }\mathbb{Q.E.D.}\text{ #}}$$

Comment: I cannot believe it I use my tablet to answer this. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot...I made two minor mistakes....

Comment: If you are interest in looking for a related post, please go to the following link http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/750358/f-y-begincases-1y-0-y-1-1-0-elsewhere-end

Comment: It seems nothing is wrong. Your answer is correct. Are you sure that's the complete question? Maybe you missed something when you were typing it.

Comment: Let chat on that question, which answer you think is right...please answer in that post

Comment: One more related post http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/750773/compare-two-estimators-by-using-the-their-expected-value-and-variances if you could help